# Correct way to add a const value inside a match string that doesn't use quotes

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My code:

```
function PaginaDoJogo() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Lesionados e Suspensos');
  const url = sheet.getRange('Menu L&S!H1').getValue();
  const team = sheet.getRange('Menu L&S!H2').getValue();
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const content = response.getContentText();
  const match = content.match(/Argentinos Jrs[\s\S]+?<!--Livestream call to action-->/);
  const regExp = /<div[\s\S]+?<span class="inj-player">(.+?)<\/span>[\s\S]+?<span class="inj-info">(.+?)<\/span>[\s\S]+?<span class="inj-return h-sm">(.+?)<\/span>[\s\S]+?<\/div>/g;
  const values = [];
  while ((r = regExp.exec(match[0])) !== null) {
    // console.log(r[1], r[2], r[3]);
    if (r[1] !== 'Name' && r[2] !== 'Away on International duty') {
      values.push([r[1], r[3]]);
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, 2).setValues(values);
}
```

`const url` is `https://www.sportsgambler.com/injuries/football/argentina-superliga/`
`const team` for example is `Argentinos Jrs`

I would like to add the value of `const team` in place of value `Argentinos Jrs` because this value can change.

Normally if the `match()` value was in quotes, just close the quotes and put:
`match("/" + team + "[\s\S]+?<!--Livestream call to action-->/")`
but there are no quotes, how should I proceed?

I've also tried using it this way but it returns in error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null (line 11)

```
  const string = "/" + team + "[\s\S]+?<!--Livestream call to action-->/";
  const match = content.match(string);
```

Comment: Have you tried the `String.prototype.replace()` function ? https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: Hi @mcanzerini But this option, as I understand it, would be for cases where I don't have access to the original value and I need to change something, in my case as I have the possibility to modify the value, there would be no way to change the string directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add escape character or extra backslash to your string when you have backslash in `RegExp()`

**Your code should look like this:**

```
function PaginaDoJogo() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Lesionados e Suspensos');
  const url = sheet.getRange('Menu L&S!H1').getValue();
  const team = sheet.getRange('Menu L&S!H2').getValue();
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const content = response.getContentText();
  const re = new RegExp(team + "[\\s\\S]+?<!--Livestream call to action-->");
  const match = content.match(re);
   const regExp = /<div[\s\S]+?<span class="inj-player">(.+?)<\/span>[\s\S]+?<span class="inj-info">(.+?)<\/span>[\s\S]+?<span class="inj-return h-sm">(.+?)<\/span>[\s\S]+?<\/div>/g;
  const values = [];
  while ((r = regExp.exec(match[0])) !== null) {
    // console.log(r[1], r[2], r[3]);
    if (r[1] !== 'Name' && r[2] !== 'Away on International duty') {
      values.push([r[1], r[3]]);
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, 2).setValues(values);
}
```

Here I printed the content of variable values:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Nikko Could you tell me why this example doesn't filter the values and instead of this pull all the names on the page? ```url``` = ```https://www.sportsgambler.com/injuries/football/usa-mls/``` and the ```team``` = ```Philadelphia```

Comment: The script didn't pull all the names on the page. If you check the data, it pull players from `Chicago Fire` up to `Minnesota`. This is because the regex is formulated to find the team name as start and <!--Livestream call to action--> as end. If you inspect element the usa-mls website, Philadelphia first occurs on this string `Philadelphia Union vs CF Montreal` which is above the `Chicago Fire` section and  `<!--Livestream..-->` occurs below the `Nashville SC`. Unlike the previous url team names didn't just occur anywhere in the html and `<!--Livestream...` occurs in every team section

Comment: Could you help me tweak this code to make it useful for both sites on sportgambler? If you want, I can create a new question talking about this problem.

Comment: Kindly create another post so that users including me can think of it. This will help the community to visualize your issue and will help you get better answers.

Comment: Here @Nikko the new question, thanks for tips! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68852962/regex-used-cannot-retrieve-correct-values-on-pages-with-similar-structures-withi

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Try something like this :

```
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Lesionados e Suspensos');
const team = sheet.getRange('Menu L&S!H2').getValue();
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
const content = response.getContentText();
const regexp = new RegExp(team + '[\s\S]+?<!--Livestream call to action-->');
const match = content.match(regexp);
```

Comment: You could also go with `const regexp = new RegExp(\`${team}[\s\S]+?<!--Livestream call to action-->\`);`

Comment: Yeah, but i wanted to keep my answer as close as the initial question with the quotes

Comment: Hi @Mccanzerini Thanks for the indications, however when trying to recover the values the null error remains, I added the complete script to facilitate the visualization of the case.

Comment: According to the doc of `match` function, the return value is an Array whose contents depend on the presence or absence of the global (g) flag, or **null** if no matches are found. Did you verify your regular expression ? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#return_value

Comment: The values in the spreadsheet added perfectly, the problem is really being when adding ```team``` into the string. Trying to use the code I put in ```My Code``` returns the values correctly.

Comment: Can you write exactly which code did you execute according to my answer please ?

Comment: Shure mate, for not extend the question, I put the script online for viewing: https://jsfiddle.net/1w93o8jx/