# Regex used cannot retrieve correct values on pages with similar structures within the same site

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

When the value of `url` = `https://www.sportsgambler.com/injuries/football/argentina-superliga/`
And the value of `team` = `Argentinos Jrs`
**The result perfectly filters only the athletes of that team.**

However, when the `url` = `https://www.sportsgambler.com/injuries/football/usa-mls/`
And when the `team` = `Philadelphia`
**The result pulls all athletes that exist on the page.**

I would like some help in finding a way to work this string so that it works on all pages of this site, because their pattern is the same, changing only the names of teams from different tournaments.

```
function PaginaDoJogo() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Lesionados e Suspensos');
  const url = sheet.getRange('Menu L&S!H1').getValue();
  const team = sheet.getRange('Menu L&S!H2').getValue();
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  const content = response.getContentText();
  const re = new RegExp(team + "[\\s\\S]+?<!--Livestream call to action-->");
  const match = content.match(re);
   const regExp = /<div[\s\S]+?<span class="inj-player">(.+?)<\/span>[\s\S]+?<span class="inj-info">(.+?)<\/span>[\s\S]+?<span class="inj-return h-sm">(.+?)<\/span>[\s\S]+?<\/div>/g;
  const values = [];
  while ((r = regExp.exec(match[0])) !== null) {
    // console.log(r[1], r[2], r[3]);
    if (r[1] !== 'Name' && r[2] !== 'Away on International duty') {
      values.push([r[1], r[3]]);
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, 2).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: Try using Javascript snippets in your developer tools.  You use css selector on a live DOM and Copy to the console in a form ready to paste into your spreadsheet.

Comment: You should try XMLService

Comment: XMLService is too sensitive to malformed html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 main issues I saw in the site and the script.

- Your `re` caught the "Philadelphia Union vs CF Montreal" instead.
- Not all `injury-block` have `<!--Livestream call to action-->` at the end.

I did manage to make it work by having it catch the team name when it is only after an `a` tag and instead of using `<!--Livestream call to action-->`, I used the `a` tag after the divs.

#### Modification:

```
const re = new RegExp("<a[^>]+>" + team + "[\\s\\S]+?<a[^>]+>");
```

In short, `team` should be in between 2 `a` tags.

[image: sample]

#### Tests:

[image: output]